# explode on "," in PHP does not work

Tags: php, explode

I have a string like this `"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQS...","data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQS","data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQS"`

What i want to do is explode it on the `","`
Like this:

```
$str = explode(" \",\" ",$str);
```

But it's seems not the work, what did I wrong ?

Comment: according to documentation http://php.net/manual/fr/function.explode.php, explode() returns an array or FALSE,  it does not return a string as you expect into `$str` variable. $str has a name reserved for string, not for array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `explode(" \",\" ",$str);` write `explode("\",\"",$str);`

You had two spaces in your regex that aren't there in your string. Therefore it won't match.

Comment: it is not a regex, if you have regex, you can use preg_split() function

Comment: You are right, it is indeed not an regex, but just a simple string pattern.

Answer (score 7):

There are no whitespaces around the `","` in the input data. That means the correct `explode` call probably is:

```
$str = explode("\",\"",$str);
```